# How to remove blank lines from a file (including tab and spaces)?

Tags: shell, command-line, text-processing, files

I want to remove all empty lines from a file. Even if the line contains spaces or tabs it should also be removed.

Comment: Is it enough to handle the well-known 6 ASCII whitespace characters, or must it handle [all 25 Unicode whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode)? Also assume you don't care about lines with only non-printable/control characters, either way. Should we assume the input is ASCII, UTF-8, Shift_JIS or could be anything?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just `grep` for non-blanks:

```
grep '[^[:blank:]]' < file.in > file.out
```

`[:blank:]`, inside character ranges (`[...]`), is called a POSIX character class. There are a few like `[:alpha:]`, `[:digit:]`... `[:blank:]` matches horizontal white space (in the POSIX locale, that's space and tab, but in other locales there could be more, like all the Unicode horizontal spacing characters in UTF8 locales) while `[[:space:]]` matches horizontal and vertical white space characters (same as `[:blank:]` plus things like vertical tab, form feed...).

```
grep '[:blank:]'
```

Would return the lines that contain any of the characters, `:`, `b`, `l`, `a`, `n` or `k`. Character classes are only recognised within `[...]`, and `^` within `[...]` negates the set. So `[^[:blank:]]` means any character but the blank ones.

Comment: should there also be a `$` for end of line?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant It's not anchored on either side

Comment: @MichaelDurrant. `[^[:blank:]]$` would only match lines that end in a non-blank. We want lines that contain a non-blank _anywhere_

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I tried grep [:blank:] SOURCEFILE even this command is working. I understand [] is for character class can you please give me some idea on how it works ? the snippet :blank: is new to me.

Comment: Are there any cases where `grep -E '\S'` wouldn't work?

Comment: @terdon `\S` is a perl regex operator, not a standard ERE one. I beleive it was also recently added to GNU regexp,  but I don't expect many other implementations would support it. In any case, it  is for *space*, not *blank*.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `\S` [is for non-whitespace](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC4), not space. It matches any non-whitespace character. I thought it was PCRE only and just found out it works on normal GNU `grep` and `sed` on my Arch which is why I asked.

Comment: @terdon I meant it's `'[^[:space:]]'` not `[^[:blank:]]`. posting on a smart phone where those characters are a pain to type. Check the opengroup site for the ERE syntax. The GNU implementation is generally not the one you want to try to test for portability as it's generally the one with the most extensions

Answer (score 35):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
$ awk NF file
```

With `awk`, `NF` only set on non-blank lines. When this condition match, `awk` default action that is `print` will print the whole line.

Comment: Neat, this also removes lines with whitespace.

Comment: `awk -i inplace NF file` to replace the file.

Comment: @wisbucky But only if that whitespace is space or tab characters. If the blank lines contain e.g. carriage-return characters, this would unfortunately not remove the line.

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
sed -e 's/^[[:blank:]]*$//' source_file > newfile
```

or

```
sed -e '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' source_file > newfile
```

i.e.

For each line, substitute:

- if it starts ("`^`")
- with spaces or tabs ("`[[:blank:]]`") zero or more times ("`*`")
- and then is the end of the line ("`$`")

More info on ::blank:: and other special characters at http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#special

Comment: `[[:space:]]` includes tabs. If it didn't your regex would fail if a space followed a tab.

Comment: The `wctype(3)` and `isalpha(3)` manpages describe what the character classes will match.

Comment: You may want to remove the first one which doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant can you please write some thing about [[:blank:]] ?

Comment: Added info for [[:blank::]].  Stephane, why doesn't the first work? I thought // at the end would replace the line without nothing.

Comment: Generally if I want to strip out blank lines as per OP, I'll use sed, but with the `-i` option to change "in place" (or "inline"). Worth reading the man page for the full caveat on using `-i`, but it saves on using a temporary output file if you have a string of inline text replacements that you need to make to a file.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I've found one not that fast, but funny at last:

`| xargs -L1`

Comment: Nice short one, but it does more: remove leading spaces and tabs as well.

Comment: Oh, it's found to be even more capable? — Nice! ;-P

Comment: And it truncates lines (default at 1024 chars) 
See manpages: https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs

Comment: This may fail to output a line that says `-n`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` command for removing blank lines:

```
sed '/^$/d' in > out
```

This command deletes all empty lines from the file "in"

Comment: That doesn't delete lines containing only space and tab, as specifically requested.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @cuonglm's answer, some lines could have non printable color characters, so removing color before running `...| awk NF` could be a good idea. In the below command, `sed` removes color from the text, `awk` then removes lines with white space.

`...| sed $'s/\e\\[[0-9;:]*[a-zA-Z]//g' | awk NF`

Answer (score 0):

Try [ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor))-way:

```
ex -s +'v/\S/d' -cwq test.txt
```

For multiple files (edit in-place):

```
ex -s +'bufdo!v/\S/d' -cxa *.txt
```

<sup>Note: The `:bufdo` command is not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).</sup>

Without modifying the file (just print on the standard output):

```
cat test.txt | ex -s +'v/\S/d' +%p +q! /dev/stdin
```

Comment: note bufdo is not POSIX http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
grep '\S' FILE
```

which removes all lines including spaces or tabs.

Otherwise, removal not including lines with spaces/tabs, use:

```
grep . FILE
```

For example:

```
$  printf "line1\n\nline2\n \nline3\n" > FILE
$  cat -v FILE
line1

line2

line3
$  grep '\S' FILE
line1
line2
line3
$  grep . FILE
line1
line2

line3
```

See also:

- Removal including space/tab lines: [How to remove empty/blank lines in a file in Unix?](https://serverfault.com/q/252921/130437)
- With `sed`: [Delete empty lines using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16414410/55075)
- With `awk`: [Remove blank lines using awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128328/21471)

Answer (score -1):

[strings](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/strings.html) looks at line-endings as something not-a-string.

```
cat file.txt | strings
```

...and all empty lines are gone.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately, `strings` only looks at "printable characters followed by a non-printable character". Space is "printable", so it will print lines that only contain spaces. The only reason why it apparently may work is because it has a lower threshold of what it considers a string (the default is 4 characters), so any line that contains less than 4 spaces and nothing else will be discarded - but so will be any line that contains less than 4 alphabetic characters. Lines with more than 4 spaces _will_ be printed.