# How to remove spaces from an input file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Sample input file:

```
abcd
<Space>
1234
<Space>
```

Desired output:

```
abcd
1234
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove blank lines from a file (including tab and spaces)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101440/how-to-remove-blank-lines-from-a-file-including-tab-and-spaces)

Comment: While your title says that you are after ways to remove spaces from a file, your example says that you want to remove blank lines. I assume the latter is your quest.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it through

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d'
```

This `sed` command deletes all lines that are empty or that only contains spaces and/or tabs.  The regular expression `^[[:blank:]]*$` matches the empty/blank lines, and the trailing `d` is a `sed` editing command that deletes them.

For example:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' <file >newfile
```

The file `newfile` will be the edited variant of `file` with the empty lines removed.

Alternatively, only output the lines with non-blank characters on them:

```
sed -n '/[^[:blank:]]/p' <file >newfile
```

This prints each line that contains at least one character that is not space or tab.  The rest of the lines are ignored.  The `-n` option to `sed` disables the default output of every line, and the trailing `p` is the `sed` command that outputs the current line (if it matches the preceding regular expression).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get rid of lines containing only spaces, as well as empty lines:

```
grep '[^ ]'   # ie, match any lines with at least 1 char different from space
```

alternatively :

```
grep -v '^ *$' # ie, hide lines that only contain spaces (0 or n spaces, ie empty lines as well)
```

if you want to also get rid of empty lines or lines with just "tabs or spaces"

```
grep -v "^[ $(printf '\t')]*$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Mandatory `awk`-based solution:

```
awk 'NF' input.txt
```

This will only print lines where `awk` detects at least one "field" (i.e. the field counter `NF` is non-zero). Note that this will also remove lines which are empty in the sense that they only contain whitespace.