# Whats the meaning of this sed command sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, regular-expression

I came across this sed command in a script to compare a machine's local binaries to GTFObins binaries.

```
    for i in $(curl -s https://gtfobins.github.io/ | html2text | cut -d" " -f1 | sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d');
do 
    if grep -q "$i" installed_pkgs.list;
    then 
        echo "Check GTFO for: $i";
    fi;
done
```

I have tested it and found that it deletes the spaces between lines, but I don't understand its form or how it is written.

Comment: Related: [How to remove blank lines from a file (including tab and spaces)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101440/how-to-remove-blank-lines-from-a-file-including-tab-and-spaces)

Comment: You probably want something like `curl -s https://gtfobins.github.io/ | grep -Po 'class="bin-name">\K[^<]+' | grep -Fxf - installed_pkgs.list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matches any line that only contains space characters between the beginning (`^`) and the end (`$`) of a line.

https://regex101.com/ is your friend.

`/…/d` instructs `sed` to delete any match, so this just eliminates empty lines (as in: no content, or only spaces, tabs and similar on the line) from the input).

Comment: Convoluted way to write `grep -vx '[[:space:]]*'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you mean "convoluted way to write `grep '[^[:space:]]'`"?

Comment: Just realized you wrote exactly that in the  answer linked the question's comments, ha!

Comment: Those are not exactly equivalent for input not fully encoded in the user's locale encoding. `grep '[^[:space:]]'` could also not return lines that contain invalid text in the locale which is why I didn't suggest it here to avoid that argument.